# Why fetchObject function is not working?

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

Why this is not working?
(Always says - empty):
When i try normal mysql it works but i want PDO in my code.

```
require_once 'app/mysql.php';
$query2 = $db->prepare("
    SELECT user_name
    FROM users
    WHERE user = :user
");

$query2->execute(['user' => 1]);

$user = $query2->fetchObject();

if (empty($user)) {
    echo "Empty!";
} else {
    echo "Working!:";
    print_r($user);
}
```

Mysql connector:

```
<?php

$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=todo', 'root');

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
$query2->execute(array(':user' => 1));
```

based on [this](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php).

You could also try this:

```
$query2->bindValue(':user', 1);
$query2->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

you have missed the : in :user in your execution command.

Which php version are you running? the shorthand [] for arrays is implemented since 5.4, I guess.